# What is the meaning of a circle next to a component pin?

Tags: integrated-circuit, signal, components, pins

I'm analyzing the schematics of `Lenovo_G530_N500_-_COMPAL_LA-4212P_JIWA3_JIWA4_-_REV_1.0Sec`. I have across scenarios where there is a circle next to a component pin. What does this circle symbolize? I have attached the screen shot for my question.

[image: screenshot of part of a schematic]

I have tried looking for a proper answer on the internet, but no satisfactory answer found.

Comment: It usually denotes active low signals. circle is similar to the circle seen in *NOT* gates.

Answer (score 5):

The circle denotes that the pin is of type *Active Low*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_level#Active_state tells that it is also indicated by

> a trailing #

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=clhdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=active+low+chip+circle&source=bl&ots=qo4h9PZV8t&sig=ACfU3U0yisUWrckGdJVVHfGPtAcJlVmuKw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVnL3mxLPqAhWymOYKHUNEBpEQ6AEwCXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=active%20low%20chip%20circle&f=false  according to this text book, the circle indicates *logical inversion*.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/288777/238590

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60401/238590